# R CRAN Neural Network Package compute vs prediction

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics

I am using R along with the neuralnet package see docs (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf). I have used the neural network function to build and train my model.

Now I have built my model I want to test it on real data. Could someone explain if I should use the compute or prediction function? I have read the documentation and it isnt clear, both functions seem to do similar?

Thanks

Comment: @bakkal Hey bakkal, do you know about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is to use `compute` to do predictions.

You can see an example of using `compute` on the test set [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-a-neural-network-in-r-neuralnet-package/). We can also see that `compute` is the right one from the documentation:

> compute, a method for objects of class nn, typically produced by neuralnet. Computes the outputs
>   of all neurons for specific arbitrary covariate vectors given a trained neural network.

The above says that you can use covariate vectors in order to compute the output of the neural network i.e. make a prediction.

---

On the other hand `prediction` does what is mentioned in the title in the documentation:

> Summarizes the output of the neural network, the data and the fitted
>   values of glm objects (if available)

Moreover, it only takes two arguments: the nn object and a list of glm models so there isn't a way to pass in the test set in order to make a prediction.

Comment: Thank you LyzandeR, I really do appreciate the answer! Could you explain what is meant in "predict" when it says "Summarizes the output of the neural network"? Im still not sure what predict is actually doing? and it takes a list of models as arguments? Sounds strange?

Comment: Np @edb500. Glad I could help. I haven't really used the `prediction` function of the package but based on the documentation and my understanding of it, it feels like it is very similar to what the function `summary` does for other models (e.g. `lm`). i.e. it feels like a summary of the neural network.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response.

Comment: I have just posted a new question, similar topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325703/r-neural-network-package-result